# knapsack problem using duality

Tags: optimization, duality-theorems

I have this knapsack problem

\begin{align}
\max {z}=10&x_1+8x_2-13x_3 +10x_4+10x_5 + 5x_6\\[0.4cm]
\text{s.t. }\quad\,\,\,7&x_1+6x_2+10x_3+\,\,\,8x_4 +\,\,\,9x_5 + 5x_6\le39
\\[0.2cm]& x_i\ge0
\end{align}

and I want to solve it using duality. I have converted it to dual but I don't know what to do next. The (D) is:

\begin{cases}
\text{min }w=&39y\\
&7y \ge 10\\
&6y \ge 8\\
&10y \ge 13\\
&8y \ge 10\\
&9y \ge 10\\
&5y \ge 5\\
\end{cases}

Comment: just take the minimum admissible value of $y$.

Comment: Don't you have an integrality constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have got the dual problem, you can see that each constraint is of the following form:
$\qquad a_iy >= c_i$

Now choose the minimum y such that all these constraints are satisfied, i.e., set y to 
$\qquad max (c_i/a_i)\; ∀ i.$
$\qquad i.e.\;y = 10/7$

Since the objective function is a constant times y, your solution is optimal.
So the optimal solution is $39*10/7 = 390/7$. 
Now a quick observation of the primal problem reveals that $x_1 = 39/7$ and other primal variables at $0$ achieves the optimal value z = 390/7 and satisfies the constraints as well.

Comment: maybe add how to obtain $x$ from $y$

Comment: @LinAlg added that part too.